# Promise chain split to perform multiple async tasks

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, es6-promise

I have a `promise` chain, at the end of which I want to perform parallel multiple waterfall operations.

```
fetchFiles(conf.src, conf.dest)
            .then(function(result) {
                return filterFiles(result, conf);
            })                                             // Here
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log("Fail: " + error);
            });
```

At the `here` position I have an array of files. I want to `foreach` the result > open file > transform > save file

**Not interested in the operations, just how to wire the operations together**

I am trying do this in ES6

Comment: Why cant you do it inside your current `.then` or chain another one on the end like `.then(function(files){...})`? Isnt that the whole point of this pattern?

Comment: @Jamiec if I do a chain like `openfile.transform.savefile` it will open all files first and not start multiple parallel operations (for the multiple files) (I think)

Comment: That won't happen if each file is mapped to a promise

Answer (score 1):

I think the following is what you're looking for.  I used Bluebird only for the `.delay` method as a matter of convenience, to simulate the different tasks taking different lengths of time.  The rest should run on ES2015 promises.  You should be able to copy paste the whole thing, `npm install bluebird` and then run the code.  You'll see that all the various tasks run in parallel and get completed asynchronously and out of order. Of course, for each file the tasks `open`, `transform`, `save` happen in sequence. (I hope nobody objects to my newly acquired distaste for semicolons)

```
'use strict'

var Promise = require('bluebird') // not needed for the actual solution

let inputFiles=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

Promise.resolve(inputFiles)  // this is your array of inputfiles
 .then(  files => {
    return files.map( file => {   // map each file to a promise sequence
      return openFile(file)
              .then(transformFile)
              .then(saveFile)
              .then(allDone)
    })
  })
 .catch( error => {
   console.error("Fail: " + error);
 })

// need to generate a promise for the opened file
function openFile(file) {
 return Promise.delay( file + '_opened',  Math.floor( Math.random() * 1000));
}

// these tasks don't need to return a promise, I'm just using
// Promise.delay as a convenience to simulate asynchrony
function transformFile(file) {
 console.log(`File ${file} opened ... Transforming`)
 return Promise.delay( file + '_transformed',  Math.floor( Math.random() * 1000));
}

function saveFile(file) {
 console.log(`File ${file} transformed ... Saving`)
 return Promise.delay( file + '_saved', Math.floor( Math.random() * 1000));
}

function allDone(file) {
 console.log(`File ${file} completed ... `)
}
```

The above will generate output like this:

```
File 6_opened opened ... Transforming
File 4_opened opened ... Transforming
File 7_opened opened ... Transforming
File 11_opened opened ... Transforming
File 7_opened_transformed transformed ... Saving
File 6_opened_transformed transformed ... Saving
File 3_opened opened ... Transforming
File 2_opened opened ... Transforming
File 11_opened_transformed transformed ... Saving
File 10_opened opened ... Transforming
File 4_opened_transformed transformed ... Saving
File 8_opened opened ... Transforming
File 12_opened opened ... Transforming
File 10_opened_transformed transformed ... Saving
File 5_opened opened ... Transforming
File 1_opened opened ... Transforming
File 3_opened_transformed transformed ... Saving
File 9_opened opened ... Transforming
File 2_opened_transformed transformed ... Saving
File 9_opened_transformed transformed ... Saving
File 4_opened_transformed_saved completed ...
File 11_opened_transformed_saved completed ...
File 6_opened_transformed_saved completed ...
File 7_opened_transformed_saved completed ...
File 8_opened_transformed transformed ... Saving
File 1_opened_transformed transformed ... Saving
File 12_opened_transformed transformed ... Saving
File 8_opened_transformed_saved completed ...
File 5_opened_transformed transformed ... Saving
File 9_opened_transformed_saved completed ...
File 10_opened_transformed_saved completed ...
File 5_opened_transformed_saved completed ...
File 3_opened_transformed_saved completed ...
File 2_opened_transformed_saved completed ...
File 12_opened_transformed_saved completed ...
File 1_opened_transformed_saved completed ...
```